# Parsing Python Response using httplib

Tags: python, urllib, httplib

After connecting to a socket and capturing the response using .read() how do I parse the input stream and read lines?

I see the data is returned without any CRLF

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/6.0.16 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - /index.html</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>/index.html</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource (/index.html) is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/6.0.22</h3></body></html>
```

Comment: and what is it you want to parse?

Comment: Maybe the read() is not working correctly yet as the output seems to be an error message

Comment: If he is receiving an error message, then it is working.

Comment: Ok, so it seems like httplib and urllib return different data. urllib worked as expected so thanks for the tip. Whoever mentioned that, urllib.read() returns the data with CRLF where as httplib.read() seems to return the data deleting the whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse the HTML. Python has several ways of parsing HTML - one of them the built-in [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) module. Another, and probably better way, is the 3rd party [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module.

Many other issues dealing with HTML processing are explained in this [nice article](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/HTML.html). You can also read the [relevant chapter](http://diveintopython.net/html_processing/index.html) of the (free online) Dive into Python book.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HTML parser.  [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) seems to be a popular one.